# \Resizebox{\textwidth} does not fit the table within the specified margins

Tags: resize, sidewaystable

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}

\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow, array, makecell}
\usepackage[counterclockwise]{rotating}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}[ht]
\centering
\caption{XXX}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{l|rrr|rrrr}
\cline{1-7}
\multirow{2}{*}{Crop} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{XXX} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{XXX} & \\ \cline{2-7}
~ &\multicolumn{1}{c}{2014} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2015} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2016} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2014} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2015} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2016} & \\
\cline{1-7}
AAA     &    24,588,220     &    21,025,436     &    28,467,038     &   -67.9   &   -14.49  &   35.39    &  \\  \cline{1-7}
BBB &   2.58    &   4.22    &   3.87    &   -57.26  &   39.94   &   24.11   &  \\   \cline{1-7}
CCC         &   9.01    &   7.95    &   6.31    &   -56.24  &   -24.60  &   7.45    &  \\   \cline{1-7}
DDD\textsuperscript{a}      &   9.39    &   6.95    &   11.90   &   -56.36  &   -36.69  &   131.70  &  \\   \cline{1-7}
EEE\textsuperscript{b}      &   0.88    &   1.27    &   1.22    &   -81.66  &   22.59   &   30.39 &     \\  \cline{1-7}
FFF\textsuperscript{c}      &   1.67    &   1.57    &   0.41    &   -53.84  &   -19.56  &   -64.81  &  \\   \cline{1-7}
GGG     &   0.08    &   0.10    &   0.10    &   -55.45  &   4.81    &   31.06   &  \\   \cline{1-7}
HHH &   0.19    &   0.23    &   0.25    &   -58.07  &   1.18    &   50.99   &  \\   \cline{1-7}
III     &   0.49    &   0.30    &   1.36    &   -54.92  &   -47.45  &   512.85  &  \\   \cline{1-7}
JJJ     &   58.76   &   60.18   &   55.56   &   -73.22  &   -12.43  &   25.00   &  \\   \cline{1-7}
KKK     &   1.12    &   1.14    &   0.25    &   -67.91  &   -12.79  &   -69.96  &  \\   \cline{1-7}
LLL     &   11.73   &   11.92   &   16.10   &   -51.17  &   -13.05  &   82.84   &  \\   \cline{1-7}
MMM     &   0.08    &   0.06    &   0.03    &   -71.80  &   -30.15  &   -31.65  &  \\   \cline{1-7}
NNN     &   0.00    &   0.01    &   0.02    &   84.98   &   -375.02 &   62.81   &  \\   \cline{1-7}
OOO\textsuperscript{d}  &   0.32    &   0.61    &   0.40    &   -44.05  &   60.23   &   -11.52  &  \\   \cline{1-7}
PPP     &   0.55    &   0.29    &   0.27    &   1709.83 &   -55.80  &   27.74   &  \\   \cline{1-7}
QQQ     &   0.05    &   0.00    &   0.02    &   9.08    &   0.00    &   0.00    &  \\   \cline{1-7}
RRR\textsuperscript{e}      &   0.17    &   0.12    &   0.35    &   -39.81  &   -36.64  &   288.47  &  \\   \cline{1-7}
SSS     &   1.17    &   1.87    &   0.86    &   -51.92  &   36.97   &   -37.69  &  \\   \cline{1-7}
TTT     &   1.76    &   1.20    &   0.71    &   -33.79  &   -41.36  &   -19.71  &  \\ \cline{1-7}
\multicolumn{8}{l}{\textit{Some text here}} \\
\multicolumn{8}{l}{\textbf{Footnotes:}}\\
\multicolumn{8}{l}{(a) Footnote a}\\
\multicolumn{8}{l}{(b) Footnote b}\\
\multicolumn{8}{l}{(c) Footnote c}\\
\multicolumn{8}{l}{(d) Footnote d}\\
\multicolumn{8}{l}{(e) Footnote e}\\
\multicolumn{8}{l}{\textbf{Other notes:}} \\
\multicolumn{8}{l}{\makecell[l]{(1) Double line text here ........................................................................................................................................................ \\ ..................................}} \\
\multicolumn{8}{l}{(2) Single line text here}\\
\end{tabular}}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

The output goes beyond the left and right margins.  I thought that resizebox can make sure this does not happen. Could it be because I used it together with sidewaystable?

Thank you.

Comment: For the footnotes in the table you might be interested in the threeparttable package. Apart from that, I'd recommend to not use resizebox to make a table fit into the textwidth as it causes inconsistent font sizes. Instead you could manually decrease the font size or change the horizontal spacing between adjacent columns.

Comment: With and also without the use of `resizebox`, I get the following (or a very similar) output:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9Ova.png  Is this similar to what you get? You could easily fit the table onto a portrait page. Would that be ok for you?

Comment: Thanks, @leandriis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `leandriis` advised, you have to change the `table footnote` tags per `threeparttable` format, and set the table in little bit small font size may solve the issue, updated `MWE` follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}

\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow, array, makecell}
\usepackage[counterclockwise]{rotating}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}[ht]
\centering
\caption{XXX}
\begin{threeparttable}
\small\begin{tabular}{l|rrr|rrrr}
\cline{1-7}
\multirow{2}{*}{Crop} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{XXX} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{XXX} & \\ \cline{2-7}
~ &\multicolumn{1}{c}{2014} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2015} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2016} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2014} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2015} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2016} & \\
\cline{1-7}
AAA     &    24,588,220     &    21,025,436     &    28,467,038     &   $-$67.9   &   $-$14.49  &   35.39    &  \\  \cline{1-7}
BBB &   2.58    &   4.22    &   3.87    &   $-$57.26  &   39.94   &   24.11   &  \\   \cline{1-7}
CCC         &   9.01    &   7.95    &   6.31    &   $-$56.24  &   $-$24.60  &   7.45    &  \\   \cline{1-7}
DDD\textsuperscript{a}      &   9.39    &   6.95    &   11.90   &   $-$56.36  &   $-$36.69  &   131.70  &  \\   \cline{1-7}
EEE\textsuperscript{b}      &   0.88    &   1.27    &   1.22    &   $-$81.66  &   22.59   &   30.39 &     \\  \cline{1-7}
FFF\textsuperscript{c}      &   1.67    &   1.57    &   0.41    &   $-$53.84  &   $-$19.56  &   $-$64.81  &  \\   \cline{1-7}
GGG     &   0.08    &   0.10    &   0.10    &   $-$55.45  &   4.81    &   31.06   &  \\   \cline{1-7}
HHH &   0.19    &   0.23    &   0.25    &   $-$58.07  &   1.18    &   50.99   &  \\   \cline{1-7}
III     &   0.49    &   0.30    &   1.36    &   $-$54.92  &   $-$47.45  &   512.85  &  \\   \cline{1-7}
JJJ     &   58.76   &   60.18   &   55.56   &   $-$73.22  &   $-$12.43  &   25.00   &  \\   \cline{1-7}
KKK     &   1.12    &   1.14    &   0.25    &   $-$67.91  &   $-$12.79  &   $-$69.96  &  \\   \cline{1-7}
LLL     &   11.73   &   11.92   &   16.10   &   $-$51.17  &   $-$13.05  &   82.84   &  \\   \cline{1-7}
MMM     &   0.08    &   0.06    &   0.03    &   $-$71.80  &   $-$30.15  &   $-$31.65  &  \\   \cline{1-7}
NNN     &   0.00    &   0.01    &   0.02    &   84.98   &   $-$375.02 &   62.81   &  \\   \cline{1-7}
OOO\textsuperscript{d}  &   0.32    &   0.61    &   0.40    &   $-$44.05  &   60.23   &   $-$11.52  &  \\   \cline{1-7}
PPP     &   0.55    &   0.29    &   0.27    &   1709.83 &   $-$55.80  &   27.74   &  \\   \cline{1-7}
QQQ     &   0.05    &   0.00    &   0.02    &   9.08    &   0.00    &   0.00    &  \\   \cline{1-7}
RRR\textsuperscript{e}      &   0.17    &   0.12    &   0.35    &   $-$39.81  &   $-$36.64  &   288.47  &  \\   \cline{1-7}
SSS     &   1.17    &   1.87    &   0.86    &   $-$51.92  &   36.97   &   $-$37.69  &  \\   \cline{1-7}
TTT     &   1.76    &   1.20    &   0.71    &   $-$33.79  &   $-$41.36  &   $-$19.71  &  \\ \cline{1-7}
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]\footnotesize
\item[]\textit{Some text here}\\
\item[]{\textbf{Footnotes:}}
\item[(a)] Footnote a
\item[(b)] Footnote b
\item[(c)] Footnote c
\item[(d)] Footnote d
\item[(e)] Footnote e
\item[]\textbf{Other notes:}
\item[(1)] Double line text here ........................................................................................................................................................ \\ .................................. \\
\item[(2)] Single line text here
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

PS: I've changed all `hyphens` into `minus` symbol, hope this is correct. Apart from if you do `decimal align` then the output looks better (here, I just followed your tags simply)...

Comment: Thanks for posting the code and changing the `hyphens` to `minus`